# AWS Glue connection error (Glue to MySql RDS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am trying to establish a connection to my MySQL RDS from Glue and ended up with the below error.

```
Unable to find a suitable security group. Change connection type to JDBC and retry adding your connection
```

[image]

I already created a role with all the below policies. Still no luck

AmazonRDSFullAccess 
AmazonS3FullAccess 
AWSGlueServiceRole 
AmazonRDSDataFullAccess

did any body faced this issue ? Any ideas ?

Thanks
Venkat

Comment: Have you tried by going back, selecting JDBC and try adding this connection as JDBC ?

Comment: @bdcloud I tried JDBC method too and ended with below error 
c2 failed.                                                                                                                
     VPC S3 endpoint validation failed for SubnetId: subnet-5cxb6711. VPC: vpc- 
     cce0c9b6. Reason: Could not find S3 endpoint or NAT gateway for subnetId: subnet-5cxb6711 in Vpc vpc-2ve0c9t6 .

Comment: Hi, This issue is resolved I lately figured out I am missing S3 end point setup, After creating end point and enabling RDS access my connection is successful